# Expected p tag in the div contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using div as a editor by giving `contenteditable=true`,

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true" >
</div>
```

Whatever user typing content except header tags it should convert into `&lt;p&gt;content&lt;/p&gt;` in `keyup` event
For example:

a) If no content in the editor, then the `div` should be

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true"/>
```

b) The user types `This is a paragraph.` without enter following. The content should be

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

c) The user erases all the previous content pressing backspace more than necessary, e.g. 25 times. The content is empty now. And rewrites the paragraph. The content should be again

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true">
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

d) The user has some text with a header (any of `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`). For example

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true">
    <p> some paragraph</p>
    <h1>a header<h2>
    <p>other paragraph</p>
</div>
```

c) The user places the cursor at the end of  `a header` and presses enter to start a new paragraph and types `This is a paragraph.` The content should have

```
<div id="edited_content" contenteditable="true">
    <p> some paragraph</p>
    <h1>a header<h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>other paragraph</p>
</div>
```

My code is:

```
var timeoutReference;
$("#edited_content").keyup(function(e) {
  var code;
  code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code === 13) {
    $("#edited_content").contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
    }).wrap("<p />");
  } else {
    if (timeoutReference) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
    }
    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
      $("#edited_content").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
      }).wrap("<p />");
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

But my code is not working in all browsers. In chrome, some times a tagless `text string` is produced under the container instead of `&lt;p&gt;text&lt;/p&gt;` in the latter, Enter creates a new `&lt;div&gt;` tag instead of a new `&lt;p&gt;` tag. Some browsers create a `&lt;br&gt;` instead of `&lt;p&gt;`

on `keyUp()`

1) Check around where the cursor is standing
2) Correct the tags
3) Place the cursor again to where the user expects it

Comment: you have asked too much. Please summaries what exactly you want.

Comment: My code is not working in all browsers. Do I want to add anything else to achieve it in all browsers?

Comment: Oh, you've more of these questions ; ). You know my opinion already. But in this post, item `a` is not possible in any browser, just because `div` must have an ending tag, and it is not self-closing.